# Path concat difference between std::filesystem and std::experimental::filesystem

Tags: c++, path, filesystems, concatenation

I was thinking to migrate from `std::experimental::filesystem` to `std::filesystem`, but my unit test started to break. I use Windows, VS2019 and MSVC compiler with `/std:c++latest`.

I narrowed the issue down to the difference between append methods (and `operator/=`) from [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append) and [experimental](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/append) code bases.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

int main() {
    std::filesystem::path p1 = "C:\\temp";
    p1 /= "\\test\\file.txt";           // Expected: C:\temp\test\file.txt, Actual C:\test\file.txt

    std::experimental::filesystem::path p2 = "C:\\temp";
    p2 /= "\\test\\file.txt";           // Expected: C:\temp\test\file.txt, Actual C:\temp\test\file.txt
}
```

**Question**: how can I use `std::filesystem` to append two path components on Windows to get  `C:\temp\test\file.txt`?

Comment: You just need to remove the slash before `test` to make it a relative rather than an absolute path?

Comment: @AlanBirtles that worked. Thanks! Do you want to write an answer for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are appending an absolute path it replaces all components of `p1`, you need to remove the leading slash from `\\test\\file.txt` to make it a relative path so that it is appended to `p1`:

```
p1 /= "test\\file.txt";
```